# Data download in parallel with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing, inputstream

So I had a url link for a file, and the file is encrypted using "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", I have the cipher key and the iv string. I am using amazon ec2 to download the data and store to `s3`. what I am doing currently is creating an input stream using `HTTPCLIENT() and GETMETHOD()` and then `javax.crypto` library on the input stream and then finally putting this inputstream in a `s3` location. Thia works for one file; but I need to scale up and do the same thing for multiple such url. How or can I take help of parallel download?

the download time for say n files is same if I don't parallelize the array of url, if I use 1 node or 4 nodes(1 master and 3 slaves). And if I use .par, it gives `out of memory` error. Here is the code for the data download and upload(the function downloadAndProcessDataFunc)

```scala
      val client = new HttpClient()
      val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build()
      val method = new GetMethod(url)
      val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
      val responseCode = client.executeMethod(method);
      println("FROM SCRIPT -> ", destFile, responseCode)
      val istream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
      val base64 = new Base64();
      val key = base64.decode(cipherKey.getBytes());
      val ivKey = base64.decode(iv.getBytes());
      val secretKey = new SecretKeySpec( key, "AES" );
      val ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivKey);
      val cipher = Cipher.getInstance( algorithm )
      cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec );
      val cistream = new CipherInputStream( istream, cipher );
      s3Client.putObject(<bucket>, destFile, cistream, metadata)
```

this is the call I do, but isn't parallelized

```scala
    manifestArray.foreach{row => downloadAndProcessDataFunc(row.split(",")(0), row.split(",")(1), row.split(",")(2), row.split(",")(3), row.split(",")(4), row.split(",")(5).toLong)
```

this runs out of memory

```scala
    manifest.par.foreach{row => downloadAndProcessDataFunc(row.mkString(",").split(",")(0), row.mkString(",").split(",")(1), row.mkString(",").split(",")(2), row.mkString(",").split(",")(3), element.replace("s3://testbucketforemrupload/manifest/", "data/") + "/" + row.mkString(",").split(",")(4).split("/").last)
```

now if i change the downloadAndProcessDataFunc function to this, it just downloads around 30/1536 such url and kills the rest of tje executors for out of memory error

```scala
      val client = new HttpClient()
      val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build()
      val method = new GetMethod(url)
      val metadata = new ObjectMetadata()
      val responseCode = client.executeMethod(method);
      println("FROM SCRIPT -> ", destFile, responseCode)
      val istream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
      val base64 = new Base64();
      val key = base64.decode(cipherKey.getBytes());
      val ivKey = base64.decode(iv.getBytes());
      val secretKey = new SecretKeySpec( key, "AES" );
      val ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivKey);
      val cipher = Cipher.getInstance( algorithm )
      cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec );
      val cistream = new CipherInputStream( istream, cipher );
      metadata.setContentLength(sizeInBytes);
      s3Client.putObject(<bucket>, destFile, cistream, metadata)
```

the variable are self explanatory

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant information in the question, so its hard to understand your issue. If the subject is parallelism, please remove all aws/encryption/serialization details and focus on the important details.

Comment: I am adding the use case, thats it. Thought it might be relevant.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read this guideline about how to write good example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In your case, the entire aws/encryption/serialization sections could be replaced with other resource-expensive code, and you'd still face the same parallelism issues. This is why those details are not important. You could minimize those to `doExpensiveThings()`.